# Enter drives for backup via keyboard

Tags: input, cmd, keyboard, backup, scanf

What I am trying to do is a backup by `cmd` commands but the problem is when I am taking the USB backup to another PC to back up the drive names are different.

For example when I do:

```
XCOPY G:\*.BMP  X:\ /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d
```

In the other computer the drives will not be `G` and `X`.

What I am seeking to do is if it is possible to make a program that I can enter with the keyboard what drive I want to backup and to what drive.

For example:

```
XCOPY "driver name keyboard input":\*.BMP  "driver name keyboard input":/" /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d
```

Comment: please check your question as I edited the post; if I changed something wrongly, please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/40754076/edit) the post again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done using a *PowerShell* or *batch-file* script (`cmd` tag seems to imply Windows OS).

Let's choose the latter. Next `batch-file` code snippet would do the same as the command in question: `XCOPY G:*.BMP X:\ /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d`:

```
set "DriveIn=G"
set "DriveOu=X"
XCOPY %DriveIn%:*.BMP %DriveOu%:\ /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d
```

Instead of hard-coded `DriveIn` and `DriveOu`, you can [prompt for user input](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html):

```
set /P "DriveIn=please choose SOURCE drive letter "
set /P "DriveOu=please choose TARGET drive letter "
XCOPY %DriveIn%:*.BMP %DriveOu%:\ /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d
```

Hints for (**necessary!**) validity checks:

```
:dfromscratch
set "DriveIn="
set "DriveOu="
:dsource
set /P "DriveIn=please choose SOURCE drive letter "
    rem basic validity check
if not defined DriveIn goto :dsource
if not exist "%DriveIn%:\" goto :dsource
:dtarget
set /P "DriveOu=please choose TARGET drive letter "
    rem basic validity check
if not defined DriveOu goto :dtarget
if not exist "%DriveOu%:\" goto :dtarget
if /I "%DriveIn%"=="%DriveOu%" goto :dfromscratch
    rem involve more validity check here!!!
XCOPY %DriveIn%:*.BMP %DriveOu%:\ /h/i/c/k/e/y/r/d
```

Some hints for (**more**) validity checks.

To show available disk drives:

```
wmic logicaldisk get Description, DeviceID, DriveType, FileSystem, VolumeName
```

To get a list of available disk drives, use [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) (note `%%G` in a batch script):

```
for /F %%G in ('
    wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType != 5" get DeviceID^, DriveType^|find ":"
    ') do echo %%G
```

or next oneliner (note `%G` in `cmd`): *copy*&*paste* into an open `cmd` window:

```
for /F %G in ('wmic logicaldisk where "DriveType != 5" get DeviceID^, DriveType^|find ":"') do @echo %G
```

Another approach (only a draft, needs more elaboration): build a list of available drive letters `%drives%` and use [`choice` command](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) instead of `set /P`:

```
set "drives=GX"
choice /C %drives% /M "Select SOURCE drive letter"
```

Comment: dude ur awsome.